# Discord.py Leveling system - Points for minutes in voice channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a Discord Bot with a leveling system, where you get points for messages. But I want to also get points for every minute in a voice channel. How can I find out when a user joins and how long he is there?

Comment: Maybe use the `on_voice_state_update` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable or data file and use `voice_state_state_update`, it is called when a user/bot joins a voice channel. (basically **invoked when voice related changes occurs**. Including muting, deafening, etc.)

```py
data = dict()
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        data[member.id] = time.time()
    elif before.channel and not after.channel and member.id in data:
        minutes = (time.time() - data[member.id]) // 60
        add_points(minutes * <points_per_min>)
```

*Note: This is just the base logic to get user's voice channel time, you have to do more checks and stuff to make it better*